# Struct Ubyte Error while connecting to MySQL database using PyMySql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am getting very weird behavior while using PyMySql.

My Connection class is as follows.

```
class MySqlConnection:
def __init__(self):
    self.host = conf.DB_HOST
    self.port = conf.DB_PORT
    self.user = conf.DB_USER
    self.passwd = conf.DB_PASSWD
    self.db = conf.DB_DEFAULT
    self.connection = None
    self.cursor = None
    #self.__connect()

def connect(self):
    self.connection = pymysql.connect(host=self.host,
                                      user=self.user,
                                      password=self.passwd,
                                      db=self.db)

    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

And there is a wrapper on top of it, which executes the query.

```
class QueryExecutor:
def __init__(self, table_name_for_query, table_attributes):
    self.conn = MySqlConnection()
    self.table_for_query = table_name_for_query
    self.table_attributes = table_attributes

def create_connection(self):
    self.conn.connect()

def close_connection(self):
    self.conn.close()
```

And then there is a table class.

```
class SupportedTables:
def __init__(self, table_name, attributes):
    self.query_executor = QueryExecutor(table_name, attributes)

def save(self):
    '''
    Inserts query for saving data in DB.
    '''
    self.query_executor.create_connection()
    value_list = []
    for attrib in self.attributes:
        if 'AUTO_INCREMENT' in attrib[1]:
            continue
        col_name = attrib[0]
        value_list.append(getattr(self, col_name))
    insert_data = [value_list]
    if len(value_list) != 0:
        self.query_executor.insert_data(data_to_insert=insert_data)
    self.query_executor.close_connection()
```

Now, when I execute tests for SupportedTables and it's derived classes, the code works fine. I do not get any issue.

However, when I try executing the code out of test class, I get an error like:

> self.query_executor.create_connection()
>   "/home/priyesh/db/QueryExecutor_v2.py", line 17,

in create_connection

> ```
> self.conn.connect()   File "/home/priyesh/db/connection_handler.py", line 24, in connect
>
> db=self.db)   File "/home/priyesh/virtualenvs/virtualenv_python3_ibsync/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 94, in Connect
>
> ```
> return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/priyesh/virtualenvs/virtualenv_python3_ibsync/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> ```
>
> line 327, in **init**
>
> ```
> self.connect()   File "/home/priyesh/virtualenvs/virtualenv_python3_ibsync/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> ```
>
> line 598, in connect
>
> ```
> self._request_authentication()
> ```

File "/home/priyesh/virtualenvs/virtualenv_python3_ibsync/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",

> line 849, in _request_authentication
>       data += struct.pack('B', len(connect_attrs)) + connect_attrs **struct.error: ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255**

**Any idea why this might be happening?** *The code is pretty simple and works from Test Class but not from Main execution script.*